# Return percentage instead of number in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Select statement:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'Black Ownership') AS Category,
    COUNT(temp.IndividualId) AS NumberForCategory,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN temp.RaceId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS AfricanHeadCount,
```

Which returns:

[image: Table]

What I am trying to achieve is that `AfricanHeadCount` column should be `NumberForCategory` divided by the entire SUM times by 100 to give me a percentage. So `AfricanHeadCount` should be `0.33` instead of 1, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Just use basic division like you normally would for a percentage: `Subset Number / Total Number = Subset Percentage` (Just note that you'll need to use decimals for a `decimal` answers.)

Comment: Why `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 'Black Ownership')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `AVG()`:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN temp.RaceId = 1 THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) AS African_percentage,
```